# "fluff and foof" What does it mean?

Tags: meaning

EDIT: I emailed the site and got the answer to my question. Apparently it means "she likes to make things pretty and fun".

I was asked about this phrase by a coworker and I have no clue what it's supposed to mean. Apparently he found it in the following passage. 
"Deanna loves to bring fluff and foof to all our events and always does a great job!!!" 
https://www.appleblossom.org/2019-board-of-directors/

At first I thought it might have been a typo but a google search gave me a few more examples.
"I’ve always heard to get pillows one size large or vice-versa, for maximum stuffing. But I specifically wanted to be able to fluff and foof mine around due to chronic back pain." 
-Amazon review for a pillow case

"Rhiannon worked at various day spas in southeast Florida in her early career, but knew she wanted more than the fluff and foof."
-Bio on an esthetician's website

Does anyone have any idea what this might mean?

Comment: Perhaps they mean that she brings all kinds of extra things that make the party great. For example maybe she always brings silly string and decorations to an event.

Comment: this is a nonsense filler phrase, in that it is actually meaningless to everybody other than the writer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Fluff" is a common word, to be found in any dictionary. It primarily** refers to soft fibers, often where we'd prefer them not to be. For example, a woman wearing a black dress might be concerned about wearing a white wool cardigan -- especially a very new one -- because it could result in her having white fluff on her dress.

"Foof", on the other hand, is not currently a dictionary work (at least, not a common one anyway), but it is somewhat onomatopoeic, given the context and its use alongside "fluff".

Together, the fluffiness and foofiness can, I suppose, contribute a certain flounce and whiffle to a sentence, but as @WendyG commented, overall it's a bit nonsensical (as is much of what I just wrote). Nothing wrong with that, of course; just read Jabberwocky to see the power of nonsense!

---

** If you look further with any depth into this, you will almost certainly discover that "fluff" has developed an *entirely* other meaning, connected with so-called "adult" movies. And for all I know, "foof", too, is a "porn name" for something. But I'd bet good money that none of that is connected with the Apple Blossom Festival, nor its Board of Directors!